# String.format() format for last characters of a string

Tags: java, string, format

is there a possibility to set a String.format argument such that the last `N` characters of the input are used, i.e. something like:

```
String s = String.format("%1${N}s", "abcdef");
```

so that `s` contains `"def"`? This is common in script languages where you can say

```
exp = "abcdef"
s = exp[-3]
```

**EDIT**

OK, so i don't want to format my data AND handle it when putting it into the `String#format` function. That's the whole point of the format description here. This format description represents a form of modularity, which is considerably broken if I have to format my input data beforehand although there is a formatter to come...

Comment: You can use substring to get the end of a String.

Comment: yes, but that requires extra handling and does not do formatting automatically.

Comment: I wouldn't consider processing/truncating a String to be formatting.

Comment: i think it IS formatting, just like when you do ellipsis.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, even now (y2017) [Java 8 Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) doesn't support "substring".

You can try:

- Freemarker and [`slicing (substrings)`](http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_stringop_slice):

  ```
  // string 'abcde', evaluates to "bcd"
  <#assign s="abcde">
  ${s[1..3]}
  ```
- Spring Expression Language (SpEL) and [`expressions methods`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-methods):

  ```
  // string literal 'abcde', evaluates to "bcd"
  ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
  String sub = parser.parseExpression("'abcde'.substring(2, 4)").getValue(String.class);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

`String#substring(int index)` does the same thing as your script example:

```
String a = "abcdef";
String b = String.format("%s", a.substring(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear whether `String.format` has this kind of function or not. But using functions of `String`, it can be realized.

```
    int n = 10;
    String a = "01234567891234";

    // Split into to strings.
    String lastString = a.substring(a.length() - n);
    String firstString = a.substring(0, a.length() - n);

    // Format second string and result is concatenated with first.
    String formattedLastString = String.format("%15s", lastString);
    String formattedString = firstString.concat(formattedLastString);
```